# printing json object with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have problem with printing json object. In firebug i can see this is returned from ajax call.

```
 ABOUT
"Company"

CONTACT
"Contacts"

FAKTY
"Facts"

KARIERA
"Career"
```

etc.

this is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'defines/defines_en.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (data) { 
        if (data.status == 200){
            alert(data['ABOUT']);
            alert(data.ABOUT);
        }
        else {
            alert("Nepodarilo sa zmeniť jazyk"); 
        }
    }
  });
```

It gives me undefined in both of those alerts.

Can someone help?

## UPDATE defines_en.php file :

```
 <?php
 $data = array(
'PORTFOLIO'=>'Portfolio',
'ABOUT'=>'Company',
'CONTACT'=>'Contacts',
'ZALOHOVANIE'=>'Backup and Archivation',
'KONSOLIDACIA'=>'Consolidation and Virtualization',
'MANAZMENT'=>'Management and Monitoring',
'NETWORKSEC'=>'Network security',
'SPRAVAKONC'=>'Správa koncových zariadení',
'FAKTY'=>'Facts',
'MGMT'=>'Management',
'REF'=>'References',
'KARIERA'=>'Career',
 );
 echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

## UPDATE 2 alert(JSON.stringify(data)) :

```
 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"PORTFOLIO\":\"Portfolio\",\"ABOUT\":\"Company\",\"CONTACT\":\"Contacts\",\"ZALOHOVANIE\":\"Backup and Archivation\",\"KONSOLIDACIA\":\"Consolidation and Virtualization\",\"MANAZMENT\":\"Management and Monitoring\",\"NETWORKSEC\":\"Network security\",\"SPRAVAKONC\":\"Spr\\u00e1va koncov\\u00fdch zariaden\\u00ed\",\"FAKTY\":\"Facts\",\"MGMT\":\"Management\",\"REF\":\"References\",\"KARIERA\":\"Career\"}","responseJSON":{"PORTFOLIO":"Portfolio","ABOUT":"Company","CONTACT":"Contacts","ZALOHOVANIE":"Backup and Archivation","KONSOLIDACIA":"Consolidation and Virtualization","MANAZMENT":"Management and Monitoring","NETWORKSEC":"Network security","SPRAVAKONC":"Správa koncových zariadení","FAKTY":"Facts","MGMT":"Management","REF":"References","KARIERA":"Career"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: That does not seem like JSON to me.

Comment: Please post value of data, not pseudo code or whatever it is

Comment: @Martin this isn't a valid JSON. For more information, go to [JSON's Official Website](http://json.org/)

Comment: don't use alert, use console.log. and, you should console.log `data` to see that it contains what you think it should.

Comment: Try this and tell what you are getting. alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: hey, i posted also php file.

Comment: Use success callback instead of complete or use the responseText of data

Comment: to debug try **console.log(data);**

Comment: @MartinFric Did you check my answer, is it working or not.

Comment: no with complete i cant access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`complete` won't return your json object, it only returns the xhr request and status text. try using `success` or `done`.

```
// one way
$.ajax({
    url: 'defines/defines_en.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data['ABOUT']);
        alert(data.ABOUT);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Nepodarilo sa zmeniť jazyk");
    }
});


// another way
$.getJSON('url')
.done(function (e) {
    // success   
})
.fail(function (e) {
    // error    
});
```

Comment: A better and elegant solution. Nice Dennis. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the responseText from the data object. Try this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'defines/defines_en.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (data) { 
        if (data.status == 200){
            response = data.responseText;
            //alert(data['ABOUT']);
            alert(response.ABOUT);
        }
        else {
            alert("Nepodarilo sa zmeniť jazyk"); 
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You won't have data.status if you use the 'success' callback unless you have specified it in your server side generated JSON

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in jquery between the 'complete' callback and the 'success' one.

If you use 'complete' then the first argument passed is a jqXHR object and not directly the data you want. So you have all your properties undefined.

If you use the 'success' callback then you have the actual data as first argument and you can use them as you are. (except for the fact that you will not have a 'status' property)

that said:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'defines/defines_en.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) { 
       alert(data.ABOUT);
},
error: function(error) {
  alert('error message here')
}});
```

documentation here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/